# Where/How do I install the SonarQube plugin for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up SonarQube to run as part of a Jenkins job but I am unable to find the correct plugin.

Looking in the Update Centre [host]/pluginManager/available I can't see a plugin called SonarQube as the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin) suggests.  There is a plugin listed called Sonar but I think that this related to an older version as the configuration options do not match the screen shots in the documentation.

The plugin is listed on the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SonarQube+plugin) but not in the [manual downloads](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/) section.

Other than downloading and building from source is there a way to install this plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Sonar was renamed to SonarQube. I believe you should use Sonar. Outdated doc is probably just that. Outdated doc :) (feel free to edit it, or propose new screenshots)

THe plugin is in the manual downloads section: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/sonar/

Comment: I think that is the old/Hudson plugin the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin) points to the newer SonarQube plugin

Comment: In Gradle, One difference between plugins: sonar and sonar-runner is, with sonar you call "sonarAnalyze" gradle task and with sonar-runner you call "sonarRunner". I have used sonar plugin in Jenkins, but that would suffice for sonar*. Look at: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job and http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341

Comment: Exactly I am lost into what I need to install. Thanks for all comments.